# org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "BaseURL" is not defined - <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

Tags: karate

I'm trying to configure a baseURL on a project. On my own project, everything work fine, but in my society's project, it says baseURL not defined.

I tried several configuration, i can't make it work ...

**log** :

```
<pre>
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "someUrlBase" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
</pre>
```

**karate.config.js**

```
<pre>
function () {

  var env = karate.env; // get java system property 'karate.env'
  karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
  if (!env) {
    env = 'dev'; // a custom 'intelligent' default
  }

  var config = {
    appId: 'my.app.id',
    appSecret: 'my.secret',
    someUrlBase: 'https://XXX',
    anotherUrlBase: 'https://another-host.com/v1/'
  }

  if (env == 'stage') {
    // over-ride only those that need to be
    config.someUrlBase = 'https://stage-host/v1/auth';
  } else if (env == 'e2e') {
    config.someUrlBase = 'https://e2e-host/v1/auth';
  }

  // don't waste time waiting for a connection or if servers don't respond within 5 seconds
  karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
  karate.configure('readTimeout', 5000);
  return config;
}
</pre>
```

**pom**

```
<pre>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>KarateeDSL</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
</project>
</pre>
```

If someone got a solution or some idea how to fix this ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I'm sorry, it is near impossible to remotely troubleshoot problems like this. I suggest you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Hello Peter, thanks for replying. 
Well, I find an easy solution - clean and verify from Maven tools. Now everything work fine. I should have thought about that much earlier...